# Rund NodeJS file in shellscript loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, loops, unix

My shellscript looks like

```
for i in {1..5}
    do
        echo "Welcome $i times"
        exec node nodefile.js
done
```

and the nodefile.js looks like

```
console.log 'running nodefile'
```

When I call the ./shellscript.sh there will only be displayed "Welcome x times" and "running nodefile" once.

Whats missing there? Is there anything that I have to return in nodefile or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for i in {1..5}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
   node process.js
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes it could be so easy :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you might try using the 'sha-bang' method.

Put this in your nodefile.js:

```
#!/the/location/of/your/node
console.log("running nodefile");
```

Then make the nodefile.js executable by doing:

```
chmod +x nodefile.js
```

Now your shell script can look something like this:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
   /location/of/nodefile.js
done
```